# Harmonize tags pdf-a and pdfx

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Well, as you can see they have a different spelling, but since they derive from PDF/A and PDF/X which have structurally the same form, the tags should do as well.  Thus I think one of them should be renamed, such that we have

**either**

> [pdf-a](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdf-a) and [pdf-x](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdf-x)

**or**

> [pdfa](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdfa) and [pdfx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdfx)

---

It turns out that this approach is flawed because it clashes with the `pdfx` package.  Actually, we'd need three tags:

- [pdf-a](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdf-a) Questions about the PDF/A standard
- [pdf-x](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdf-x) Questions about the PDF/X standard (does not yet exist)
- [pdfx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdfx) Questions about the `pdfx` package

Comment: Personally I like the version with the hyphen for the PDF standards (which would ignore the package `pdfx` which contains no hyphen).

Comment: @TeXnician That's actually a good point.  I totally forgot that there is the [`pdfx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfx) package which could also be referred to by the tag.  Now that is a bit of a clash, but since people use `pdfx` to create PDF/X, the usage of a possible [tag:pdf-x] should be self-explanatory.

Comment: `pdfx` is a package, so many instances of the `pdfx` tag refer to the package, rather than to PDF/X technology. In fact, it seems that most tags `pdfx` are actually asking about PDF/A technology, which is also part of the `pdfx` package.

Comment: @RobtAll so we should create another tag so that we have `pdf-a`, `pdf-x`, and `pdfx`?

Comment: @Skillmon It turns out that this question would actually incur a tremendous amount of retagging which has to be done by hand.  A question could use the `pdfx` package with the PDF/X standard in which case it should be tagged pdfx and pdf-x.  However, a question regarding the PDF/X standard without the `pdfx` package would only be tagged `pdf-x`.

Comment: @Skillmon I really don't know what is best. What you suggested seems good. The underlying problem is that most users of package `pdfx` actually use PDF/A (pdf-a), based on questions I've seen here. Now, when someone chooses tags, each tag has a little explanation of what it means. That's where you would distinguish between `pdfx` (package), `pdf-x` (technology) and `pdf-a` (technology).

Comment: @RobtAll only problem would be the massive retagging as mentioned by Henri, which I didn't consider when first writing the comment.